# Use a Delegate Control on a content page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, delegate-control

I created a delegate control which compares the address a user linked from (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path) and if it is correct, I provide a link to a given url.  I would like to use this in a content page and not the master page. Is this possible?

If I place it on my custom masterpage, the code responds favorably.  I need the link on a site page however.

Thanks!